# Force evaluation of Mul(tiplication) in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Multiplication distributed over addition in sympy does not seem to evaluate the multiplications.

I've made a subclass of `sympy.Symbol` that knows how to multiply itself by other things.  As a minimal working example, let's just pretend the subclass just eats up anything that's multiplied by it:

```
from sympy import *

class Gobbler(Symbol):
    _op_priority = 1.0e200
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Gobbler('gob('+self.name+'*'+str(other)+')')
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return Gobbler('gob('+self.name+'*'+str(other)+')')

x = Gobbler('x')
y = Gobbler('y')
a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')
```

[Yes, that `_op_priority` is ridiculous.  But changing it to more respectable numbers ~10.0 doesn't change anything.]  I can run

```
>>> x*a
gob(x*a)
>>> x*a + y*a
gob(x*a) + gob(y*a)
```

Everything works quite naturally until I get to

```
>>> expand((x+y)*a)
x*a + y*a
```

Why don't these get gobbled?!  The result looks exactly like what I entered at the previous prompt, but nothing happened.

The Gobblers are now factors in `Mul`s, two of which are terms in an `Add`.  So how can I make those `Mul`s evaluate?  I've tried every combination of `simplify`, `expand`, etc., with every combination of options I can think of.  But nothing makes these go anywhere.  I can even extract the first half of the sum with `.args[0]` and try to simplify/expand that.  Nothing!

Even worse, my actual use case involves lots of nested expressions like

```
>>> b*expand((x+y)*a)
b*(x*a + y*a)
```

What is going on?  How can I make it work?  What's the magic word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not what I had hoped for, but I think the solution will necessarily involve going through the expression and forcing the applications.  Applying such applications is like applying `simplify`, so it's not too unexpected or onerous.  The following is sufficient for my purposes, though more general expressions might require more special cases.  The essential ideas are found [here, in the tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html), and involve recursing through the expression tree:

```
def gobbleExpr(expr):
    if isinstance(expr, Gobbler):
        return expr
    if isinstance(expr, Mul):
        args = list(o if o.is_Atom or isinstance(o, Gobbler)
                    else gobbleExpr(o)
                    for o in expr.args)
        gobbler = prod(t for t in args if isinstance(t, Gobbler))
        others = prod(o for o in args if not isinstance(o, Gobbler))
        if gobbler==1:
            return others
        else:
            return gobbler.__mul__(others)
    if isinstance(expr, Add):
        return sum(gobbleExpr(arg) for arg in expr.args)
    return expr
```

So now I can do something like

```
>>> expand(b*(x+y)*a)
x*a*b + y*a*b
>>> gobbleExpr(_)
gob(gob(x*1)*a*b) + gob(gob(y*1)*a*b)
```

So the only remaining things are `Gobbler`s added to each other, which I handle elsewhere.

Comment: You should just use a simple `else: return expr.func(*[GobbleExpr(i) for i in expr.args])`.

Comment: You mean if not isinstance of Gobbler or Symbol?  This doesn't do anything for me; the result is just unevaluated `Mul`s, etc.

Comment: Your code only handles Gobbler, Mul, and Add. The else will make it handle everything.

Answer (score 0):

Mul doesn't call `__mul__` (`__mul__` is only called when you use a `*`, as it's Python's operator overloading). SymPy currently doesn't provide a way to dispatch on Mul, though it's on our TODO list. The main thing holding it back is that we aren't really sure how to do it. Your solution is probably the best way (except with the correction I mentioned).

You can also play with setting `_op_priority` (search the SymPy code-base to see how to use this).

Comment: Yeah, I think it's acceptable to have to do something like `gobbleExpr` explicitly, much like `simplify`.  But it would be nice to have some sort of hook into `simplify` to do the job -- so some method in my class that `simplify` would look at and simplify any node containing my object as one of the `args`, then propagate that down the tree.  (Maybe there is such a thing and I just don't know about it.)

Comment: BTW, I set `_op_priority` various reasonable and ridiculous values, but it never changed anything.

Comment: You can define an `_eval_simplify` function, which will be called by `simplify` on your objects. This lets objects simplify themselves, but not necessarily themselves in relation to the rest of the expression, so this needs some more thought.